# Do we need nginx before tomcat if I have elastic load balances?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elb, elastic-beanstalk

My current configuration setup is as below,

```
AWS ELB(https / 443 to 80) --> Webserver_UI ( nginx 80 ) -> nodejs 

AWS ELB2(https / 8080 to 8080) --> Webserver (nginx 8080) -> localhost tomcat 8081 -> Java code
```

Now my question is Do I really need Nginx for my 2nd webserver? As tomcat can be directly taking the request from AWS ELB and certificates are taken care by ELB itself.

But every one keep Nginx, so what is the real advantage of this setup?

I know I can try "AWS Elastic Beanstalk" instead of nginx  but on cost wise I don't want to try it.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the application and NGINX configuration as NGINX may improve performance in many cases - especially for serving static files and caching.

Comment: Generally, nodejs will be running on different port and nginx will forward request from 80 to that port. so better to keep the settings otherwise you need to modify other settings in AWS like open  port and  other security  etc

Answer (score 0):

What kind of load you expect (number of users, frequency of use like calls per minute) and how much is your static content?

My current product in alpha stage where i dont expect more than 100 users in next few months is running directly off tomcat (on EC2, no ELB) doing SSL, serving static content and REST APIs. Will optimize if my server is not able to handle things and i can always just bump-up my instance type or serve static content via S3.

I searched for this sometime back more in security context but couldn't find anything. The only reason I would use Nginx or Apache web-server is if it can provide some extra security but i wasnt able to find anyone using them for security purpose.